# Faster implementation for shuffling buckets in a dataset? Python

Tags: python, optimization

Is there a faster way to implement this?  Each row is about 1024 buckets and it's not as fast as I wish it was..

I'd like to generate quite a lot but it needs a few hours to complete as it is.  It's quite the bottleneck at this point..  Any suggestions or ideas for how to optimize it would be greatly appreciated!

Edit*
Apologies for not having a minimal working example before.  Now it's posted.  If optimization could be made for Python 2.7 it would be very appreciated.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import copy
import random

def number_to_move(n):
 l=math.exp(-n)
 k=0
 p=1.0
 while p>l:
         k += 1
         p *= random.random()
 return k-n



def createShuffledDataset(input_data, shuffle_indexes_dict, shuffle_quantity):
  shuffled = []

  for key in shuffle_indexes_dict:
      for values in shuffle_indexes_dict[key]:
          temp_holder = copy.copy(input_data[values[0] - 40: values[1]]) #may need to increase 100 padding

          for line in temp_holder:                 
              buckets = range(1,1022)

              for bucket in buckets:        
                bucket_value = line[bucket]
                proposed_number = number_to_move(bucket_value)
                moving_amount = abs(proposed_number) if bucket_value - abs(proposed_number) >= 0 else bucket_value

                line[bucket] -= moving_amount

                if proposed_number > 0:
                    line[bucket + 1] += moving_amount
                else:
                    line[bucket - 1] += moving_amount

          shuffled.extend(temp_holder)

  return np.array(shuffled)


example_data = np.ones((100,1024))
shuffle_indexes = {"Ranges to Shuffle 1" : [[10,50], [53, 72]]}

shuffle_quantity = 1150

shuffled_data = createShuffledDataset(example_data, shuffle_indexes, 
shuffle_quantity)
```

Comment: Could you post minimal, WORKING code? Otherwise its going to be challenging. Which version of python is this?

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight!  It's for Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some minors things you might try:

1. merge key and values into single call:

   for key, values in shuffle_indexes_dict.iteritems():
2. use xrange rather range
3. bucket values seem to be integer - try caching them.

   ```
   _cache = {}
   def number_to_move(n):
    v = _cache.get(n, None)
    if v is not None: return v
    l=math.exp(-n)
    k=0
    p=1.0
    while p>l:
        k += 1
        p *= random.random()
    v = k-n
    _cache[n] = v
    return v
   ```
4. If shuffle_indexes_dict ranges are exclusive, then you can - probably - avoid coping values from input_data.

Otherwise i'd say you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I'll look up caching to see if it works. What do you mean by exclusive?

Comment: Ahh.. the issue is I'd like to create multiple copies of each dataset.  Without copying, the original dataset gets modified and it would affect later duplications.. no way around that right?

Comment: Nope, sorry. Once you start modyfing, you need to copy.